# Java Regex: Grouping is not right

Tags: java, regex

I Wanna check the validity of a string then try to split it using regex.

The regex should group the input by ";" and each group should be a key-value pair,but my regex group the inputs wrong,where is the problem with my regex?

Here is my function that uses regex:

```
    public static boolean verify(String str) {
    String pattern = "^(Eval:)+((.+?)=(([^;]*$)))+";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
    if(m.matches()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Valid Examples:**

Eval:tag=val;tag2=

Eval:tag=val;tag2=val2

Eval:tag=

Eval:tag=;tag2=

**Invalid Examples:**

Eval:tag=;tag2=;

Eval:tag;tag2=;

Eval:tag=tag2=

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @shmosel you're right!

Comment: `Eval:tag=;tag2=` <-- is this really valid?  I would hate to be the person who is working with your data if this be the case.

Comment: Btw, you can replace the whole method with `str.matches("^(Eval:)+((.+?)=(([^;]*$)))+")`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes,it's following the rfc6265 for validating cookies

Comment: The regex you are looking for is extremely complex.  Are you certain that rfc6265 does not already have libraries in Java to handle this?

Comment: just the structure of the data is same as the cookie rfc6265 not the fields & ...,so i can't use any of existing java libraries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
^Eval:((([^=;]+)=([^=;]*));?)+(?<!;)$
```

It's basically the same as your attempt, but with a negative look-behind for `;` at the end to block the trailing semicolon.

- **Header** `Eval:`
- **Tag=** `([^=;]+)=`
- **Optional Value** `([^=;]*)`
- **Semi colon delimited Tag=Value list** `((([^=;]+)=([^=;]*));?)+`
- **Can't end with a semi-colon** `(?<!;)$`